# Getting the key of a directory in the registry

Tags: delphi, windows-xp, registry, directory

How to get the key of a especific directory in the registry of windows XP?

I'm using Delphi

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\Bags`

Answer (score 1):

There are no directories in the registry. The registry contains *keys* and *values*. The values have *names* and *data*. The keys are *like* directories, though.

If you want to inspect the contents of a key, you can use the `TRegistry` class. Set its `RootKey` property to `HKey_Current_User`, and use its `OpenKeyReadOnly` method to open the subkey. Then you can use the various `Read` methods to read the data of any value.

If you're not sure what the type is of a data entry, you can use the `GetDataType or`GetDataInfo` methods.

To read a list of all the data entries' names, you can use `GetValueNames`.

All of those are documented in the help, and now that you know their names, it should be easier for you to find many examples.

Comment: Calm down!! some directories have a specific key in the registry, and are listed in the address that I showed. I need to know the key of a especific directory.

Comment: OK. So what directory do you want to know about? What do you want to know about it? Since I've already told you how to get information from the registry, I can only assume that you don't know what information you need. So what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: How to get the key of a especific directory(any) in the registry of windows XP?

Comment: You already said that. What trouble are you having with that task?

Comment: *You* calm down. Repeated punctuation won't help. Is there something special about the *particular* directory key you mentioned? Does that key hold information about certain directories, but without indicating *which* directories? And are you having trouble deciphering the storage format? Is *that* what you wanted to ask about? You can't just paste a registry key at the bottom of your question and expect people to figure out what you're asking. Use complete sentences to introduce ideas.